# Return first XElement in node with greatest number of fields

Tags: c#, xml, linq

LINQ gurus, I have a quick one.

Say I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xamDataPresenter version="12.1.20121.1010" formatVersion="1.6">
  <fieldLayouts>
    <fieldLayout key="ems:airportsType" >
      <fields>
        <field name="IKO" />
        <field name="Name"  />
        <field name="the_geom"  />
        <field name="DistanceKm" />
        <field name="DistanceNm" />
      </fields>
      <recordFilters />
    </fieldLayout>
    <fieldLayout key="ems:airportsType" >
      <fields>
        <field name="IKO"/>
        <field name="na3" />
        <field name="Name"/>
        <field name="Type"/>
        <field name="the_geom"/>
        <field name="Mod_time" />
        <field name="Country" />
        <field name="Operator"/>
        <field name="Contact"/>
        <field name="DistanceKm"/>
        <field name="DistanceNm"/>
      </fields>
      <recordFilters />
    </fieldLayout>
  ......
  </fieldLayouts>
</xamDataPresenter>
```

What is the LINQ syntax I use to get the **fieldLayout** node with the most **field** elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var res = XDocument.Load(filename)
                .Descendants("fieldLayout")
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Descendants("field").Count())
                .First();
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fieldLayout = xDoc.Root
                      .Element("FieldLayout")
                      .Elements("fieldLayout")
                      .OrderByDescending(fl => fl.Element("fields")
                                                 .Elements("field")
                                                 .Count())
                      .First();
```